# Are Uber webhook event ids unique across all user profiles?

Tags: uber-api

I am storing Uber webhook events in my DB as there may be cases where the same event is fired twice for different scopes, as mentioned here : https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks . I am handling multiple user profiles, and want to know if the events are unique across users. If not, I need to store both the event id and the user the event was generated for in my DB model.

Answer (score 1):

The event id **should** be practically unique across space and time as it is a [UUID - Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) generated using [Version 4 (random)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) of the [RFC 4122 Variant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) specification.

```
  "event_id": "3a3f3da4-14ac-4056-bbf2-d0b9cdcb0777"
```

Version 4 UUIDs have the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B

The version 4 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from truly-random or pseudo-random numbers.

Which depending on the quality of the generated cryptographic random numbers / if sufficient entropy was feed into the generator, the resulting event ID should be more or less globally unique. (less/more chance of a hash collision)